# Editable datagrid inside a combo box in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, combobox

Is it possible to show an editable datagrid inside a combo box? I have to show the columns of another datagrid in one column and the filter condition in the second column.

which is the best way to do this?

Comment: Why you want to edit that? i mean you just want to display it right???

Comment: Denish, i need to filter another datagrid based on the conditions i specify on this datagrid(which is inside a combo box)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can template the combobox to display a datagrid in it.
If you are not using dotnet 4, you will find the DataGrid control in the [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx)

Comment: If you bind data on the same data source it will

Comment: Meziantou, i am using .net 4, is this feature available in the datagrid which is built into .net 4

Comment: .net 4 Datagrid is the same datagrid as the toolkit datagrid.